# Grab text from listbox datatemplate

Tags: c#, wpf

*This is a simpler version of a bigger project of code, I'm also quite new to coding so a simpler response would be even more helpful.

What I want is to grab what ever the client_name.text is from the selected list box item. So if I were to select the first item in the list then it would output "James Henry".

```
<ScrollViewer>
            <ListView Name="client_list">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Name="client_name" Text="{Binding Text}"></TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
</ScrollViewer>
```

XAML

```
    public class ListAdd
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
```

Code

```
        client_list.Items.Add(new ListAdd() { Text = "James Henry" });
        client_list.Items.Add(new ListAdd() { Text = "Alexander Makuros" });
        client_list.Items.Add(new ListAdd() { Text = "Justin Crevis" });
```

What I want to happen -->

```
        int index = client_list.SelectedIndex;
        String ClientName = client_list.grabvalue(index, Client_Name.Text);
        Console.WriteLine(ClientName);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in the right direction.

```
int index = client_list.SelectedIndex;
string clientName = ((ListAdd)client_list.Items[index]).Text;
```

Even better if you just get the selected Item

```
string clientName = ((ListAdd)client_list.SelectedItem).Text;
```